# Rails, Sass and Grunt

Tags: import, rubygems, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm trying out switching to using Grunt for all my asset stuff in my Rails app rather than the asset pipeline. (Just a trial, I can dispose of this and go back to asset pipeline at any time)

I have the grunt-contrib-watch plugin watching and compiling my sass files but it's failing with the line:

`@import "bourbon"`

Grunt does not seem able to find the bourbon files. I have bourbon installed as a gem. I know grunt-contrib-sass has a `loadPath` option but I am unsure of what to add to this to allow Grunt to see and use the gems installed as part of my bundle?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you install bourbon you put:

```
bourbon install;
```

This command creates a folder named **bourbon**. and you have to import it using

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
```

You have to check where is the bourbon folder. And import it.

I think it's not a Grunt problem, because Grunt does not know if a sass code uses bourbon, compasss, susy or whatever.

Regards.

Comment: I solved this by using the require option of grunt-contrib-sass

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the require option of `grunt-contrib-sass`:

```
require: ['bourbon', 'susy', 'breakpoint'],
```

I now need to find an equivalent for loading in javascripts from ruby gems such as jquery from the jquery gem and jquery-ujs from jquery-rails gem.